# NSMutableOrderedSet removeObjectAtIndex not working consistently

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableorderedset

I tried to delete entries from an NSMutableOrderedSet. The behavior is inconsistent, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

```
    NSMutableOrderedSet* detailPlaylist;

    [detailPlaylist removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
before the removal:

(lldb) po [detailPlaylist objectAtIndex:0]
{
    videoDuration = "5:15";
    videoId = "i-bu47QpWWc";
    videoSelected = n;
    videoThumbnailData = {length = 10595, bytes = 0xffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 ... 84200421 0801ffd9 };
    videoThumbnailUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i-bu47QpWWc/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEiCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDFQgBFQAAAAAYASUAAMhCPQCAokN4AQ==&rs=AOn4CLDbkeqgCWR4RSyTpUhI9IM2Gd2poA";
    videoTitle = "\U5f35\U60e0\U59b9 A-Mei - \U7ad9\U5728\U9ad8\U5d17\U4e0a  \U5b98\U65b9MV (Official Music Video)";
}
(lldb) po detailPlaylist.count
1

///////
after the removal:

(lldb) po detailPlaylist.count
1
(lldb) po [detailPlaylist objectAtIndex:0]
error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): no variable named '_cmd' found in this frame
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-7)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Comment: *"sometimes it works and sometimes it does not"* -- not much we can do to help with that... You need to try to determine a pattern of actions that causes it ... then update your questions with code / description of actions that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DonMag Thx for replying! There is no pattern as I can find. The code is that single line removeObjectAtIndex. By executing that line, the count of items in the set should be one less. But sometimes, the count remains the same as I print in the console. But if I try to print the object at that index (0 in the example posted), an error comes up (as in what was posted above).

Comment: @DonMag No worries. I think I found what caused the issue. The detailPlaylist is not an independent object.

Comment: I've seen the debugger lie before, caching the description from a previous "po" command and repeating it, even though the reality is different if the method was actually called.

Comment: @CarlLindberg This one is totally my overlook. I forgot the set was part of another data structure.